# Spring + Freemarker + Hibernate(EM) + MySql UTF-8 chars at server-side

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, encoding, freemarker

I'am working on a small Spring powered application. I have a form with some text fields , but after POST, at server side, this fields content loses for example ś, ć chars . They become replaced by their utf-8 code: '&#243'; etc. They are saved in this way in MySql db. When i get this data from db and display they in the freemarker based view layer they are displayed correctly. But how can I get proper chars at server-side ?

I added this in the head of my template
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">`

I setted encoding for the database

I configured Hibernate like this:

persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="evPU">
 <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.CharSet">utf8</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">utf8</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</property>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

context.xml

```
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/*****?characterEncoding=UTF-8" />
    <property name="username" value="****" />
    <property name="password" value="****" />
</bean>
```

Finally, I used a filter

web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

But nothing of this solved my problem. Someone can give me a clue?

**Solved**

I added this property in viewResolver bean at context.xml

```
<property name="contentType" value="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure the form accepts UTF-8 with:

<form accept-charset="UTF-8">

2. Remove the character encoding filter in web.xml.

Comment: I tried point 1 but no effect. That just changed the code which replaces the chars.  Could You explain why should I remove the filter from web.xml?

Comment: It looks like your content is getting doubly-encoded somewhere.  The filter is a likely place where that may be happening.

Comment: I applied your's suggestions but no effect